# Not able to update a Zoho Project Task Work Hours

Tags: zoho-deluge

In Zoho Projects, I've created a quick Deluge script that is to run whenever a task is closed and take a value from a custom field and edit the "Work Hours" to match that amount.

```
owners = testResponse.getJson('tasks').getJSON("details").getJSON("owners");
no_of_owners = owners.size();
custom_fields = testResponse.getJson('tasks').getJSON('custom_fields');
proposed_hours = "";
for each  item in custom_fields
{
    if(item.getJson('label_name') == "Proposed Hours")
    {
        proposed_hours = item.getJson("value");
    }
}
info proposed_hours.toLong() / no_of_owners;
value_update = Map();
owner_work = List();
count = 0;
for each owner in owners
{
    owner_map = Map();
    owner_map.put("user_id",owner.getJson('id'));
    calc = proposed_hours.toLong() / no_of_owners;
    owner_map.put("working_hours", calc.concat(""));
    owner_work.add(owner_map);
}
value_update.put("owner_work", owner_work);
info owner_work;
update_response = invokeurl
[
    url :projectsDomainURL + "/portal/" + portalId + "/projects/" + projectId + "/tasks/" + taskId + "/"
    type :POST
    parameters:value_update
    connection:"*********"
];
info update_response;
```

The Rest API indicates that a json array should be passed in with user_id and working hours ([Link to the relevant spec](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/tasks-api.html#alink5)). However this is not changing the values as expected but accepts the request as valid and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to specify the work hours parameters:

```
value_update = Map();
value_update.put("owner_work",{{"user_id":assignee_id.tostring(),"working_hours":"0.5"}});
value_update.put("work_type","work_hours");
```